# How to write sub query in zend 2

Tags: mysql, zend-framework2

SELECT 
booking_request.book_id,
booking_request.pickup_loc,
booking_request.drop_loc,
booking_request.journey_date,
booking_request.return_date,
booking_request.distance,
booking_request.est_fare,
DvrExp.expenses AS expenses,
PndBal.pending AS payment_Pending,
PymtRcvd.receive AS Payment_Recevied,
booking_details.car_id AS car_id,
booking_details.car_name AS car_name,
booking_details.driver_id AS driver_id,
booking_details.driver_name AS driver_name
FROM booking_request
 LEFT JOIN booking_details
    ON booking_request.book_id = booking_details.book_id
LEFT JOIN(
       SELECT book_id,
        SUM(amount) AS expenses 
FROM driver_expense GROUP BY book_id) DvrExp
ON DvrExp.book_id = booking_details.book_id
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT book_id, 
        SUM(amount_pending) AS pending
 FROM payment_balance GROUP BY book_id) PndBal 
ON PndBal.book_id = booking_details.book_id
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT book_id,
        SUM(amount) AS receive 
FROM payment_receive GROUP BY book_id) PymtRcvd
ON DvrExp.book_id = booking_details.book_id 
WHERE booking_request.status = 'Closed'

Answer (score 1):

Please see the last example (#17 - starting on line 268) of a gist I created on Github:
https://gist.github.com/andrewscaya/8b7d53cffd7c1cb61c234c0de126e964

For future reference:

```
    use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;
    use Zend\Db\Sql\Where;
    use Zend\Db\Sql\Expression;

    $sqlExpression = new Expression('MAX(`sku`)');
    $subSelect = new Select();
    $subSelect->from('purchases')
            ->columns([$sqlExpression]);
    $where = new Where();
    $where->in('sku', ['sku' => $subSelect]);
    $select = new Select();
    $select->from('products');
    $select->where($where);
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing from booking_request in main select clause

```
    SELECT booking_request.book_id
    ,booking_request.pickup_loc
    ,booking_request.drop_loc
    ,booking_request.journey_date
    ,booking_request.return_date
    ,booking_request.distance
    ,booking_request.est_fare
    ,DvrExp.expenses AS expenses
    ,PndBal.pending AS payment_Pending
    ,PymtRcvd.receive AS Payment_Recevied
    ,booking_details.car_id AS car_id
    ,booking_details.car_name AS car_name
    ,booking_details.driver_id AS driver_id
    ,booking_details.driver_name AS driver_nameFROMbooking_request
FROM booking_request
LEFT JOIN booking_details ON booking_request.book_id = booking_details.book_idLEFT
JOIN (
    SELECT book_id
        ,SUM(amount) AS expenses
    FROM driver_expense
    GROUP BY book_id
    ) DvrExp ON DvrExp.book_id = booking_details.book_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT book_id
        ,SUM(amount_pending) AS pending
    FROM payment_balance
    GROUP BY book_id
    ) PndBal ON PndBal.book_id = booking_details.book_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT book_id
        ,SUM(amount) AS receive
    FROM payment_receive
    GROUP BY book_id
    ) PymtRcvd ON DvrExp.book_id = booking_details.book_id
WHERE booking_request.STATUS = 'Closed'
```

Comment: I think the question was more about how to build that request using zf. Not about the strict sql syntax, but i might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
$select = $this->getSql()->select();
    $select->join('booking_details','booking_request.book_id = booking_details.book_id',array('car_id', 'car_name','driver_id', 'driver_name'),"LEFT");         


    $select->join(array('DvrExp' => '(SELECT book_id, SUM(amount) AS expenses FROM driver_expense GROUP BY book_id)'),'DvrExp.book_id = booking_details.book_id',array('expenses'),"LEFT");
    $select->join(array('PndBal' => '(SELECT book_id, SUM(amount_pending) AS pending FROM payment_balance  GROUP BY book_id)'),'PndBal.book_id = booking_details.book_id',array('pending'),"LEFT");
    $select->join(array('PymtRcvd' => '(SELECT book_id, SUM(amount) AS receive FROM payment_receive GROUP BY book_id)'),'PymtRcvd.book_id = booking_details.book_id ',array('receive'),"LEFT");     
    $select->where("booking_request.status = '".$booking_type."'" );
    $this->_set_date_filter($select,$params);
    $select->where("booking_request.request_date > '2016-06-07 00:00:00'" );    

    //echo $select->getSqlString(); die;
    $resultSet = $this->selectWith($select);        
    return $resultSet;
```